# Using Grunt to process handlebar template files into mysql database

Tags: mysql, file, gruntjs, handlebars.js

I'm looking to use grunt to process templates (handlebars and static html files) into a mysql database table. I currently use grunt to compile handlebar templates on the client side. However, we need server support for these templates, which the best approach is to store the templates into a mysql db table.

Is there a standard grunt package that will process the content of files and store them in a mysql table? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is "no", there is no grunt package that does this entire task.

There is `grunt-contrib-handlebars` which will compile Handlebars templates for you, and there are a few Grunt/MySQL packages that will do various tasks with MySQL, but none of them are for inserting rows into MySQL databases.

However, Grunt is just JavaScript running in NodeJS, and can easily connect to any MySQL server you have access to, at which point any library method can be run, including importing any arbitrary SQL data into your server.  Just install the NodeJS MySql driver: `npm install mysql`.  Then you can import the MySQL library into your Gruntfile and use it:

`var MySQL = require('mysql');`

The code you would need to write would be some JavaScript in a grunt task that whips your compiled Handlebars template strings into some SQL that can be run against your server.

Not trivial, but not exactly advanced either, and totally doable.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was thinking needed to be done; but making sure that I had to take it there.